# Existence of $k$-dominating set whose induced subgraph has bounded degree $k-1$

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I would like to know if there is any piece of literature which discusses the existence, for any undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, of a subset $V'⊆ V$ such that every node not in $V'$ has at least $k$ neighbors in $V'$, but also, every node in $V'$ has at most $k-1$ neighbors in $V'$. In other words, $V'$ is a $k$-dominating set of $G$, and every node in the subgraph induced by $V'$ on $G$ as degree at most $k-1$.

I feel like such a subset should always exist but I am struggling to find a hard proof.

Comment: I tried but alas, I can't. It's just a gut feeling I have. I know that for $k = 1$ it is true as the maximum independent set satisfies the condition, but why do you say that it is obviously true also for $k = 2$?

Comment: My question was only about finite graphs, so your answers are much appreciated. Both proofs are very interesting, but still, I feel like the set could exist for all finite graphs, not just r-regular ones.

Comment: The question originates from a setting in which all nodes in a graph are considered agents in a game, whose utility functions make them prefer to be in the set if at most 2 neighbors are also in the set. After some research I figured that the problem of existance of a pure Nash equilibrium was equivalent to that of the existance of a $[\sigma, \rho]$-set with $\sigma = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and $\rho = ℕ \setminus \{0, 1, 2\}$.

Comment: Note that your conjecture is equivalent to an ostensibly more general statement, which could conceivably be easier to prove: For any finite graph $G=(V,E)$ and any function $f:V\to\mathbb N$ there is a set $W\subseteq V$ such that $W=\{x\in V:|N(x)\cap W|\lt f(x)\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if the following is a potential proof to this fact:

Let $S$ be a vertex subset of $G$ that maximizes
$$(k - 0.5)|S| - |e(S)|$$
where $e(S)$ denote the number of edges in the subgraph of $G$ induced by $S$.

If some $v \in S$ has at least $k$ neighbors in $S$, we can remove $v$ from $S$, getting
$$(k - 0.5)|S\backslash\{v\}| - |e(S\backslash \{v\})| \geq (k - 0.5)(|S| - 1) - (|e(S)| - k) > (k - 0.5)|S| - |e(S)|$$
contradiction.

If some $v \notin S$ has less than $k$ neighbors in $S$, we can add $v$ to $S$, getting
$$(k - 0.5)|S + \{v\}| - |e(S + \{v\})| \geq (k - 0.5)(|S| + 1) - (|e(S)| + k - 1) > (k - 0.5)|S| - |e(S)|$$
contradiction.

So $V' = S$ satisfies the desired proposition.

Comment: I think you can leave it there... it contains many valuable ideas as well...

Comment: It looks sound to me. Very elegant and compact!

Comment: Very nice. And it follows that, for any locally finite graph $G=(V,E)$ and any function $f:V\to\omega$, there is a set $S\subseteq V$ such that $S=\{v\in V:|N(v)\cap S|\lt f(v)\}$.